# SSH SOCKS5 proxy, is my traffic being kept safe?

Tags: ssh, osx, proxy

So I've been running everything on my system through my SSH SOCKS5 proxy. All the network commands I type in the terminal, I use proxy chains, and I have my system set to use my SOCKS5 proxy globally so that Safari uses the proxy, Vuze, etc.

I see within my Activity Monitor (I'm on OS X) that all my traffic is going out my SSH process and coming in through my SSHD process. Oh and I'm using port 9050, not 1080.

Now, my question is: is this really keeping me hidden or would someone be able to capture my traffic with Wireshark and decrypt it?